# Sometimes player moves too much

Tags: c++, movement, box2d

I'm working on a simple platform game.
I have the player - a dynamic body, which moves by `ApplyLinearImpulse`.
Generally it works very well, but sometimes the player moves to much.

For example - I'm making short clicks on the keyboard, every click the player moves for example 50 pixels, but once in a few clicks it will move 200-300 pixels.

The code of the movement:

```
void GameObject::move_phisical_body_horizontally(const float x)
{
    float velChange = x - m_phisical_body->GetLinearVelocity().x;
    float h_impulse = m_phisical_body->GetMass() * velChange;
    m_phisical_body->ApplyLinearImpulse(b2Vec2(h_impulse, 0), m_phisical_body->GetWorldCenter(), true);
}
```

the code of the ground object: (the ground is a collection of ground tiles)

```
auto& texture = Resources::instance().getTexture(GroundTexture);
auto width = texture.getSize().x;
auto hieght = texture.getSize().y;
auto position = this->convert_position(position_vec, { width, hieght });

b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
bodyDef.userData.pointer = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this);
b2Body* body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);


b2Vec2 v0((position.x - width) / SCALE, position.y / SCALE);
b2Vec2 v1(position.x / SCALE, position.y / SCALE);
b2Vec2 v2((position.x + width) / SCALE, position.y / SCALE);
b2Vec2 v3((position.x + width * 2) / SCALE, position.y / SCALE);

b2EdgeShape edge1;
b2EdgeShape edge2;

edge1.SetOneSided(v0, v1, v2, v3);
edge2.SetTwoSided(v1, v2);

b2FixtureDef FixtureDef1;
b2FixtureDef FixtureDef2;
FixtureDef1.density = 0.f;
FixtureDef1.shape = &edge1;
FixtureDef2.friction = 1;
FixtureDef2.shape = &edge2;
body->CreateFixture(&FixtureDef1);
body->CreateFixture(&FixtureDef2);

m_phisical_body = body;
```

The code of the player:

```
auto width = 32u;
auto hieght = 32u;
sf::Sprite sprite(Resources::instance().getTexture(PlayerTexture));
sprite.setPosition(position_vec.x * width, position_vec.y * hieght);
sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect({ 0, 0, (int)width, (int)hieght }));
sprite.setOrigin(16.f, 16.f);

auto player_obj = std::make_unique<Player>(sprite, std::vector<int>{ 11, 12, 1, 1, 1 }, "player");
player = *player_obj.get();

auto position = player_obj->convert_position(position_vec, { width, hieght });

b2BodyDef BodyDef;
BodyDef.position = b2Vec2(position.x / SCALE, position.y / SCALE);
BodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
BodyDef.userData.pointer = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&player);
b2Body* body = world->CreateBody(&BodyDef);
body->SetFixedRotation(true);


b2PolygonShape Shape;
Shape.SetAsBox((width / 2.f - 1) / SCALE, (hieght / 2.f - 1) / SCALE);
b2FixtureDef FixtureDef;
FixtureDef.density = 1.f;
FixtureDef.friction = 1.f;
FixtureDef.shape = &Shape;
body->CreateFixture(&FixtureDef);
player.set_phisical_body(body);
```

Comment: Perhaps the physics loop in box2d is running multiple times? So you're setting a velocity using an impulse, and that velocity is continuing for multiple frames before you see the result? Also from the class reference, SetLinearVelocity looks like a more intuitive way to set the velocity to what you want, or even use SetTransform to set the position directly, without relying on the underlying physics, if you're trying to move it by a fixed amount rather than use an acceleration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by setting the player's friction to zero and just handled the deceleration by myself instead of letting the box2d handling this.

```
void GameObject::update_deceleration(const float  friction_decrease)
{
    auto velocity = m_phisical_body->GetLinearVelocity();

    if (velocity.x)
    {
        velocity.x *= friction_decrease;
        if (abs(velocity.x) < 0.3f)
            velocity.x = 0;
    }
    m_phisical_body->SetLinearVelocity({ velocity.x, velocity.y });
}
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your problem. Don't forget to accept your own answer, it will help people having the same problem in the future!

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: Short answer: click on the checkmark next to your answer. You'll find all relevant information here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.